# True or False List combination

Tags: python, list

Could someone please explain why the following does not achieve the desired output.

I have two list: l1 and l2.
I want to check if either value is 1 in each list and return this to a 3rd list l3.

Have
[1,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,1]

Want
[1,1,0,1]

I have figured out how to get the desired output with list comprehension:

desired = [1 if i[0]==1 or i[1]==1 else 0 for i in list(zip(l1, l2))]

But I am still not sure why the alternate method gives the wrong output.

```
l1 = [1,1,0,0]
l2 = [0,0,0,1]
l3 = l1 or l2
print(l3)
```

OUTPUT:
[1, 1, 0, 0]

Also if you reverse the order, l3 = [l2 or l1] you get a different output.
Can someone explain?

Thanks

Comment: There are add-ons to Python that allow such vectorized operations. I believe Pandas is one such thing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The `or` operator returns its left hand or right hand operand, *as is*. The `or` operator does not process operands in any way and doesn't have any special handling if the operands are lists. It simple returns the first list that's truthy, *as is*.

Comment: BTW, you can simplify your solution to this: `[a or b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]`.

Comment: Functional version: `from operator import or_` `map(or_, l1, l2)`  or `list(map(or_, l1, l2))` if you need a list.

Comment: may be you are looking for `!=` operator

Answer (score 1):

here `l3 = l1 or l2` is checking if value of `l3` will be `l1` if `l1` has any value ie `l1` is not empty or None, otherwise it will be equal to `l2`

you can understand this will following example

```
>>> x= [1]
>>> y = []
>>> z = x or y
>>> z
[1]
>>> z = y or x
>>> z
[1]
```

Note it is not processing internal element of list, it is just checking that object is not empty or None if not that assign that object otherwise assign other one